# Does multiplying all elements of a planar equation change the plane that the equation describes?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a planar equation of:

$$0=-5x-2y+\frac{3z}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$$

The solution manual states that the answer to the question I am solving is:

$$0=10x+4y-3z-3$$

My understanding is that these two equations are equal because each value is being multiplied by the same amount, and we can multiply my equation by -2 to get the same result as the solution manual (thanks to the zero on the other side). Am I correct? This is difficult for me to visualize in my head (because surely multiplying all of the numbers would make the plane "bigger"?)

Comment: For example, $(0,0,-1)$ is a solution of the first equation. Is it a solution of the second? The plane is really about the solutions of the equation, not the equation itself.

Comment: @BobJones That is a solution of both equations. So, based on that, my assumption seems to be correct, because any possible values that are a solution to the first equation will be a solution to the second equation, because each element will change proportionally in the same way to any possible solution?

Comment: Absolutely, you got it.

Comment: @BobJones Thank you very much, that makes it much easier for me to visualize.

Comment: Equations of planes, lines, algenraic curves, &c.,  are defined up to a non-zero constant factor.

Answer (score 0):

- $x-2=0$ is an equation that is satisfied by one number, namely $(2)$.
- $3x-6=0$ is another equation that is satisfied by one number, again $(2)$. It is *equivalent* to the first equation since any solution of one is a solution of the other. Ditto $(x-2)^2=0$, or $x^2-4x+4=0$, or $x^2+4=4x$.
- $(x-2)(x-3)=0$ is satisfied by two numbers, so is not equivalent to either of the previous equations. It is equivalent to each of $x^2-5x+6=0$, $4(x-2)(x-3)=0$ and $2x^2-10x+12=0$, however.
- $x+y-1=0$ is an equation satisfied by any and all points of the form $(a,1-a)$ for any real number $a$. Again, $5x+5y-5=0$ is equivalent to this equation.
- On the other hand, $5x+5y-1=0$ is not equivalent to this equation.
- An algebraic set of points can be described by many equivalent equations: all that matters is that the set of solutions is the same. Hence $(1+x^2)(x-y)=0$ is equivalent to $x-y=0$ if one is working in the real numbers, because then there are no points that satisfy $1+x^2=0$.
- In particular, multiplying by a constant does not change the solution set, so the two planes are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're dealing with linear algebra; however, it might help you see that they're the same plane by looking into vector equations of lines and planes. I suggest you take a look at this. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfPlanes.aspx

In brief, $ax+by+cz=d$ is what we call the scalar equation of a plane, where $d=ax_{0}+by_{0}+cz_{0}$ for a point $P_{0}=(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ on the plane. Notice that if we are given the equation of a plane in this form we can quickly get a normal vector for the plane.  A normal vector is, **n**$=<a,b,c>$.

So we have that the coefficients are merely the position of a orthogonal vector that we use to describe the direction of our plane. Thus, multiplying the equation by an integer wouldn't be changing the nature of the plane, but merely obtaining a different orthogonal vector which is a scalar (is parallel) of the first one.

Also notice that we have infinitely many vectors such that they are normal (perpendicular) to our plane, and therefore we have infinitely many vectors we could use to describe its direction; namely, there are infinitely many equations that would be representative of our plane.

Answer (score 0):

No, those two equations are not equal and you know that but what is equal is that they represent exactly the same plane in the space.

If you "multiply the first plane" with $-2=(-1) \cdot 2$ then that corresponds to rotation of that plane by  $180$ degrees, that is $-1$, and then streching the plane by a factor of $2$ in all directions.

But with those two processes you obtained exacty the same set of points in the space, so your plane is transformed to exactly the same plane.